# Save and load text font in textview. (Xcode)

Tags: xcode, fonts, colors, load, save

I was wondering if any one knew how to save an load fonts on a textview. The app lets the user select the font for the text view but when they switch views and come back it is gone. Does any one know how to save that and then load it. Thanks so much.

Also if any one know how to save text color that would due great also.

Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is to give all the textViews a specific tag values and on navigation before view willDisappear you have to store all the values to array and on navigating back to the view on viewWillAppear fill all the textViews using the tag values.

Comment: Okay thanks so much. I am new to Xcode is there any way you could maybe give me a source code. Thanks so much!!